# Passing argument with special character in restful webservice

Tags: url, rest, special-characters, parameter-passing

How should i pass argument containing special characters in restful GET function?
DO i have to encode the argument value?
If so how would i do it?
The arguments that i have pass is USB0::0x164E::0x13EC::TW00008555
and *IDN?

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encode unreserved characters with so-called [percent hex encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

The arguments would be encoded as `USB0%3A%3A0x164E%3A%3A0x13EC%3A%3ATW00008555` and `%2AIDN%3F` respectively.

Comment: can i pass them simultaneously? does restful support passage of multiple parameter?

Comment: Yes. Usually the full URL will look something like `http://service.example/path-to-resource?usb-id=USB0%3A%3A0x164E%3A%3A0x13EC%3A%3ATW00008555&reason=%2AIDN`. This passes the arguments using names `usb-id` and `reason` respectively.
Note that I erroneously said you did not need to encode your example parameters. In fact you *should* encode them.

Comment: thanks for replying mate, as you can see from my second parameter which is *IDN? "?" is a special character which is also used by rest to pass an argument, will it create any conflict while passing the argument? or do i also have to encode it? is there any inbuilt java function that could do the encoding for me? and BTW mate i tried passing the first argument and i got the result without any problem. The problem is with passing the second argument.

Comment: Haha, I had not realised. Yes you *have to* encode it then. I edited the response regarding this.